# Could producing a grave bug that made headlines make you unemployable?

Tags: hiring, employment, mistakes

Does producing such a grave bug like [Log4Shell](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-313) make you effectively unemployable?

The people involved have committed under their real names and, taking into account how prominent the bug is, it's easy to assume that every potential employer googling for a candidate's name will learn that they were involved in this incident.

Can such an error be forgiven and, if so, under which circumstances? I'd expect that making a grave error as junior isn't a no-go because juniors are expected to make errors. However, employers wouldn't expect seniors to make the same mistakes.

For non-IT people: This [introduced a critical security vulnerability to log4j2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell):

> Affected commercial services include Amazon Web Services, Cloudflare, iCloud, Minecraft: Java Edition, Steam, Tencent QQ and many others. According to Wiz and EY, the vulnerability affected 93% of enterprise cloud environments.

> The exploit allows hackers to gain control of vulnerable devices using Java. Some hackers employ the vulnerability to utilize the capabilities of the victims' devices; uses included cryptocurrency mining, creating botnets, sending spam, establishing backdoors and other illegal activities such as ransomware attacks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132407/discussion-on-question-by-danubian-sailor-could-producing-a-grave-bug-that-made).

Comment: Hey everybody. Comments have already been moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132407/discussion-on-question-by-danubian-sailor-could-producing-a-grave-bug-that-made). Please, use such chat room to continue the discussion. Further comments may be removed without warning...

Comment: For non-IT people, probably the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) is more accessible.

Comment: This question is being [discussed](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7016/should-questions-about-problems-that-someone-other-than-the-op-faces-be-allowed) on Meta.

Comment: Norrington: You are without a doubt the *worst* pirate I’ve ever heard of. - Captain Jack Sparrow: But you *have* heard of me. - *[Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl, 2003]*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Does producing such a grave bug like Log4Shell make you effectively
> unemployable?

Absolutely not.

I follow the [Edward Deming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Edwards_Deming) principles. Systems are to blame, not individuals.

> I'd expect that making a grave error as junior isn't a no-go because
> juniors are expected to make errors. From a senior, however, you
> should expect the ability to spot the most obvious mistakes.

It was 8 years ago. For all I know, the developer was an intern at the time, but even if he wasn't. Eight years is a lifetime in this field.

> it's easy to assume that every potential employer googling for candidate's name will learn...

If anything, this could make an interesting interview topic. So the developer just needs to be prepared to talk about what happened, and what he has learned from those mistakes, in case this topic ever comes up during his interviews.

Comment: To add to the interview topic level, it's worth noting that how they respond to the issue is fairly relevant - and if they understood what conditions led to the situation that happened. With that much information ,even the ["Three Gateway Protocol" that BGP is infamous for being](https://www.stuff.co.nz/technology/digital-living/69048160/the-three-napkins-protocol-quick-fix-for-early-internet-problem-left-web-open-to-attack), can be recognized as an achievement even if Pakistan was able to block YouTube.

Answer (score 155):

Your mistake is thinking that this is a bug. It isn't. It's a feature that someone wanted, and the developer implementing it did so without any bugs that we know of. In hindsight, it was a very, very stupid feature. Actually, insanely stupid - but only with the point of view of the year 2021, when every computer on the internet is under constant attack. In 2000, when the feature was created, nobody did think of it. And the feature was in the open, and for 20 years nobody had the bright idea to exploit it.

So no, there is no problem for these developers whatsoever.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132406/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-could-producing-a-grave-bug-that-made-headlin).

Answer (score 85):

- No, the bug definitely can not be compared to that.
- Missing quality assurance, tests and wrong prioritization are never a single persons fault
- The impact of a bug has very often nothing to do with how stupid it was to make.
- Seniors who believe only Juniors make mistakes are more dangerous.

Comment: FYI: the comparison OP made has been edited out of the question.

Comment: This is not even a bug. It's a feature that should have never passed security review, if they even had one as part of the process.

Comment: `Seniors who believe only Juniors make mistakes are more dangerous.` -  ```Nobody actually creates perfect code the first time around, except me. But there's only one of me.``` -- [Linus Torvalds](https://youtu.be/4XpnKHJAok8?t=1337s)

Comment: It was a feature that someone wanted. I would be sure that it was tested properly, was found working, and was used. There was no bug that testing would have found. What was found years later was that the feature could be abused to create massive damage.

Answer (score 46):

> Could producing a grave bug that made headlines make you unemployable?

If all you care about is what bugs/mistakes a candidate has produced then maybe.

Or, if like most normal hiring managers, you look at the totality of their knowledge and experience and allow them to explain any mistakes in their past, it is much less likely that the candidate is "unemployable".

A proper analogy would be any coach/player of a professional sport making public mistakes (usually on live television to audiences of millions).  They somehow seem to be employed after making those mistakes.

Comment: Stack Overflow itself could be another example. If you hang out on Meta Stack Exchange, you'll sometimes see on bug reports specific employees posting an answer that includes something like, "This was my mistake". (I can't recall if an individual has ever tried to take responsibility for anything that would be considered a larger issue but they don't seem to fear publicly admitting they made an error.)

Comment: Also, having made a mistake you're _possibly_ more likely to avoid something similar compared to someone who hasn't.

Comment: To continue the sports analogy: The receiver missing a catch for the game winning touchdown. The pitcher giving up the game winning home run. The goalie not blocking a penalty kick. These are all mistakes that can cost not only a single game but a championship deciding game. The players remain employed under their current contracts and can often get paid more at their next contract negotiation. There was a great Nike commercial with Michael Jordan listing how many game winning shots he'd _missed_ - ended by saying "_because_ I missed them, I am who I am today". [con't]

Comment: Failure isn't the end unless you let it be the end. If an employer is so small minded that they see one failure in your past and totally discount all the good you've done, they're doing you a favor because you wouldn't want to work for them anyway.

Comment: The sports analogy is faulty. In sports, one team is _expected_ to fail. A proper analogy is when one's actions cause significant financial loss or death, e.g. a stock trader who loses hundreds of millions, or a pilot who crashes a plane.

Answer (score 27):

It's important to note that log4j is NOT a bug. It is a deliberate feature.

The developer didn't make a small error. They didn't make a typo. They didn't forget a corner-case.

The implemented probably the most dangerous feature they could have envisioned, and turned it on by default.

The fact is, it would probably have been better if it was a bug, because at least then we would have known it wasn't intentional.

The person who implemented this feature refers to themselves as a "security software engineer". If they were applying for a job, I would want to understand what that thought process was.

Did they consider the wide ranging implications of their change? Did they consider the risk factors? Or did they just implement the feature as asked, without any consideration to impact on the many users that would be exposed? Did they just consider it not their problem to deal with the fallout? Was there malice involved?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132426/discussion-on-answer-by-gregory-currie-could-producing-a-grave-bug-that-made-hea).

Answer (score 24):

I'd just figure you'd never make THAT mistake again.

I like to say, "I don't lose, either I win, or I learn"

Truth be told, most people are like that.  A mistake, even a high profile mistake is not an overall representation of the person, their skills, or their ethics.

At my company, we would go right to a post-mortem and figure out what went wrong and how to prevent it.  It's usually a mistake on several levels, and it is more important to prevent it from happening again, than it is to assign blame.

So, nobody would be unemployable for a mistake, but it would close a few doors, and quite frankly, they are doing you a favor, because a company that would not accept the fact that people make mistakes is not one you really want to work for.

Comment: To be fair though, it's possible to learn from other people's mistakes. It's how we move forward as an industry.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It's possible to make mistsakes nobody else has?  It's how we learn from our mistakes that we move forward as an industry.

Comment: This is not a mistake that nobody else has made. This is a very obvious problem for anyone that is even slightl knowledgeable about security.

Answer (score 11):

### No, because it requires that you made something important

In order for a bug you created to hit headlines like, you first have to make something that is used widely enough to be important. Log4j's bug is important, because log4j is used by a large number of important projects who chose it because of its quality.

So, yeah, you take a hit for the bug but that doesn't really measure up against the bigger factor of being someone who is capable of creating such a project in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

Let's speak generally and not in the particular Log4j example which is not comparable to the common "grave bug that makes headlines" issue.

We are humans. We make mistakes. Everyone does. Moreover, common software projects involve several people and not just one individual, so even if a single person could be blamed for the bug, the rest share responsibility with it cause they all work in the same codebase. A colleague at a former job I had, would tell me "there is no bug in *my code* or *your code*, there is a bug in *the code*".

Everything boils down to why the bug happened and how it was handled. If there was intention, which is extremely rare, that is quite a red flag for employment for sure.

More commonly, there will be negligence instead. That person not taking enough cautions on its work to ensure the delivered code was of high quality and secure. In this case, it is just a negative annotation to consider in the full person's record, but even then, how was the issue managed? Did that person involve themselves into fixing the bug ASAP? Did they learn a lesson and now are more careful about not making that mistake again? Even if all answers are negative, you have to see it in perspective and consider the environment this person worked on and the chance that this could happen in your own company if you hired that person, so it is really a hard choice to make.

Then, there will be times where the bug was reasonably difficult to find out, and where all due cautions were taken and still the bug got out. You cannot blame the developer for causing the bug in that situation.

Finally, somebody making these headlines could actually be a hint that this person's previous work had a high impact. It's not easy to work at a project that powers 10% of the whole Internet!

Answer (score 6):

An extreme example: [Kevin Mitnick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Mitnick) is employed as a security consultant, and he was *jailed for hacking*.

So, no: mistakes made do not necessarily affect your employment prospects, as long as you can show that you've grown past them and that you've got the expertise.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?  Did Mr. Mitnick introduce a bug?  Did he make a mistake?  The best burglars make the best testers of burglar defence systems and virtual burgling (hacking) is no exception.

Comment: My point is that it's all about reputation and trust.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Mitnick does not have reputation of being incompetent.

Comment: Breaking the law is a mistake, though. At least according to most societal framings.

Answer (score 4):

I am firmly of the opinion that for any bug to make it to production, then two things must be wrong.  People make mistakes.  And therefore, if a single person's mistake can cause a disaster, then there's something wrong with the process.  Both the testing and the code review processes must have been inadequate, for a bug to slip through to production.

So either three people are responsible (the creator of the bug, the reviewer and the tester), or the development process is broken.  In short, the developer by themselves is never to blame.

Having said that, if I were an interviewer who learnt that the person I'm interviewing was involved in the creation of such a howler, one question I would ask them would be what they've learnt from the experience.  In other words, what are they doing differently now, from what they were doing when the original problem arose.  Their answer to that question alone probably tells me whether or not I want to hire them.

Comment: If you expect that there's a single piece of code on this planet that is devoid of bugs, I'd consider you delusional.

Comment: Right, if your security plan is "don't make mistakes", then be glad you don't fly airplanes for a living.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it is that any news is good news. While making a critical error is bad, it shows that 1) you have a community that uses your products, and 2) now you can show you're committed to your product by fixing it and releasing an emergency patch.

It's sort of like when Facebook got hacked and all their user information got leaked. At the same time, all your information is already "sold" so the reality is a leak means Facebook just didn't make the revenue when they would sell the same information to advertisers.

Can you get fired? It really depends on the culture and I imagine if the bug can be fixed rapidly. I don't think a normal company would fire someone on the spot as they'd want it fix. So at least you're safe until the bug gets fixed. But after which, sure you might get into trouble. No way to know and it probably depends on how often you normally do such a bad thing and exactly the mood of everyone in the company.

Answer (score 1):

### Producing a bug - no, managing such project - maybe

Developers do make mistakes. Someone is having a bad day, lack of sleep, problems at home, simple oversight ... Lots of things get committed.

However ... on any serious project, even if open-source, after that initial commit, there should be code reviews, testing, regressive testing and other QA techniques. Especially if project in question impacts so many people and other applications. Person responsible for organizing all of this, be it a team lead, scrum master, project manager or whatever ... should be taken under scrutiny if something like this appears.

This not necessarily means that this bug is caused by organizational flaw, but it should be examined how did it manage to slip trough cracks.

Comment: This "bug" was actually a deliberate feature, and would have passed all QA.

Comment: If this were actually a requirement, people would just not contribute to open source projects. Further, if you aren't satisfied with the quality of software as developed for free by someone else, you're perfectly welcome to create your own version on your own time with your own resources.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It would not. Part of QA process is establishing potential security flaws.

Comment: @user3067860 Life is not fair. If you participate in open source project with your own name, especially such important project, you are not doing it just of goodness of your heart. Participating in Log4j project is credential enough to land you decent job elsewhere. Unfortunately, stick has two ends.

Comment: @rs.29 The feature is actually bug free and is designed to not be secure.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yeah, right :D That is why they first disabled it, and then completely removed it. All by design :D

Comment: @rs.29 I don't think it's accurate to call this a part of QA process. I've been in security trainings in some past jobs and per my recollection most reasonable approach (both for QA and developers) is to stay away from security matters and instead do only and exactly what _professional_ security experts tell them to do. You are free to call these security professionals "also QA" if you wish, except that they are not. They are security experts and this is a separate full-time profession

Comment: QA checks if the software does what it is supposed to do. It did. _Normally_ security problems make the software misbehave. Here the exploit was the designed behaviour.

Comment: @rs.29 So? Life isn't fair stick hits both ways, too. You got something for free and it turned out not to be absolutely perfect? Cry me a river. (And then go implement your own solution and see how well you do. If you think your solution has no problems or security holes, I guarantee that's simply because no one has looked for them. No known problems = lots of unknown problems.)

Comment: @gnasher729 Wrong. QA also supposed to check does new feature breaks something in existing functionality. Regressive testing is a serious business.

Comment: @gnat Well, you have been trained wrong :D Security testing is part of general QA. Especially in critical projects (libraries used by others, like in this case) QA is definitely concerned with security. What you propose is simply "passing the buck" to "security experts" that may not even exist in the team.

Comment: @rs.29 I've been in such projects and there certainly was security testing but it was fully controlled by professional in security. Dev and QA (me included) took part in it but we merely followed instructions written by these folks, without slightest creativity and deviations. As I wrote, you are free to call security professionals QA, except that they are not

Comment: @gnat As you said yourself, security testing was part of QA process. What title do you give to these people is irrelevant. What is important is the fact that you cannot release serious product "into the wild" without security testing. If this happened, then person responsible for the project needs to answer few questions.

Comment: Log4j is not a "serious" project - not in the sense usually given to commenrcial projects (the very fact that contributors aren't paid makes typical criteria of commercial projects irrelevant). And your attempt to mix security professionals into generic QA makes me uncomfortable because not all projects can afford them and not all projects must involve them (Log4j is one of such projects if you think of it, it passes the buck to commercial projects utilising it and this is normal and expected). Not to mention that they don't even have "QA" in the sense of one used in commercial projects

Comment: @gnat Ludicrous :D Log4j is one of the most critical projects in Java, because almost any other application uses it, including (for example) those in banking/financial sectors. I'm not responsible for your feelings, but QA in general includes security testing. Not everyone could afford that - well, this is true, but then the quality of the product you could assure is not that great.

Comment: in past jobs I worked in sensitive projects that used log4j (and tons of other potentially insecure open source projects). Management of these projects just hired security professionals to audit and test involved projects just the same way as they did to in-house code. Things just work this way. You either pay to professionals to handle all your software including its open source parts and get its quality properly assessed. Or you skip that, pretending that unpaid volunteers of open source project do all this very expensive, complicated, boring work and then, well, the fault is all yours

Comment: @gnat How come those "security experts" did not find this security flaw in log4j ? Well, for obvious reason that people working on one project do not have time to test common and shared libraries. Imagine how much it would cost to test whole JVM for security before deploying your application. And not just one, all Java versions that could be used on various servers.

Comment: wonder what makes you think that they didn't. Per my observations typical "lifecycle" of such vulnerabilities is that experts learn about the problem and its solutions long before it becomes public knowledge. And they apply that knowledge in their recommendations to the paying customers

Comment: @gnat Well it is obvious they did not because now many companies scramble to change affected versions of that library on their production servers.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case there should be no risk. For one, there is no one bug to point to, everything was working as intended, and known to every user (or even just reader of the documentation) from the very start. Yes, one person asked for the feature; one person implemented it, but many, many persons witnessed it and said nothing.

But more importantly, there is another point of view: as an employee, I would not want to be employed in a company (or below a manager) without a modern/agile error culture. IT in general is very complex, and having a positive error culture is one of the hardest, but also most productive features of an organization.

So, no, there is no risk in committing open source with your real name in this regard - assuming most open source commits are from people who do what they love to do, this is always a great way to demonstrate their knowledge and interests to possible employers. If employees select against that, then this is  a useful filter against a combination that maybe would not have worked out anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> producing such a grave bug

Software development is a team effort. In my opinion, the **developer** didn't produce a bug; they implemented a [documented feature](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/lookups.html#JndiLookup) instead.

Usually, in a product development organisation, when a developer is finished with an implementation, they send it off to QA for review. So, instead of blaming the developer, I would actually point fingers at the **quality assurance** process -- or perhaps more appropriately at the **product owner**. Whose idea was it that a logging framework should support automatic object deserialization via JNDI? What does that have to do with logging?

Every time you implement a marginally useful feature, you introduce a possibility for bugs due to the increased complexity. Keep things simple, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)!

Comment: Being able to look up strings in JNDI _is_ a simple thing.  They just missed the ldap feature.

Answer (score -1):

Quality Assurance is usually the responsibility of the company or maybe the team. Very rarely the individual who causes the bug (if it can even be traced to a specific person).

Also, they would definitely not be unemployable. There is **a lot** of demand for bugs these days.